# Hiding email from spambots without using javascript

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention

I have a "contact us" form that uses Ajax (i.e. relies on asynchronous requests).

In case the user has javascript disabled, I want to display a message, saying something like:

> You need to enable Javascript to use this contact form. If you can't, or don't know what Javascript is, then use your email and contact us at `<the_email_address>`.

But of course, I want to hide `the_email_address` from spambots.

Since this email address has to be displayed inside a `<noscript>`, it makes no sense to scramble it with Javascript, specially given the fact that some users may simply not even know what Javascript is.

I thought of a solution but I have no way to test it: Inserting empty `<span></span>` tags, as in

> `my_em<span></span>ail@g<span></span>mail.com`

Or, a bit cleverer

> `my_em<span style="display:none">garbage</span>ail@gmail.com`

Would that work? If not, any better ideas?

**Update**

Thanks RichieHindle for the ansewr. I thought I'd share a simple implementation of the idea in python:

```
def html_nospam(string):
    def ent(char):
        return "&#%d;" % ord(char)
    return ''.join([ent(c) for c in string])
```

Comment: Note: Be careful, with these "tricks" you not only hide your e-mail from bots, but also from people with disabilities.

Comment: @Zed, good point, though for my particular case (read: my audience), they're not likely to use the form anyway, or they'd have someone assist them with it or do it for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use HTML entities to obfuscate it.  `x@y.com` becomes `&#120;&#64;&#121;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;`.

You'd think address harvesters would be wise to that, but many aren't.  The end result for the user (whether he's using a browser or a screenreader) is indistinguishable from the normal text.

There are [online tools](http://alicorna.com/obfuscator.html) you can use to do the conversion for you.

Comment: Awesome. This sounds like the way to do it.

Comment: @hasen, it is - I have seen this quite often.

Comment: sarnath'd to this - but I think this is the way to go or as Shoban suggested, you can try the Facebook way - the email addresses in their profiles are images.

Answer (score 4):

What about an image?

[alt text http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/s.png](http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/s.png)

or use [microsoft tag](http://tag.microsoft.com/) :) to look cool

[alt text http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/My_Contact_2009829838261.jpeg](http://www.codegeeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/My_Contact_2009829838261.jpeg)

Edit: Just read your comment above regarding your audience. Looks like MS tag will be too much for them :)

Comment: +1, Use a pencil instead of inventing a pen that works in 0 gravity. Eh? Good one.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I did. The problem is it's not copy-paste-able

Comment: @hasen j if it's not copy-paste-able then it's a little bit harder to be spam-able? :P

Comment: @pageman, but also more likely for visitors to mistype it, or be confused (and pissed) because they can't select/copy the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an image. Or use Flash (or Silverlight, ActiveX, whatever).