# How can I obscure email addresses on websites to prevent spam?

Tags: html, email, spam-prevention

I know this is a bit broad, but the questions is how can I obscure my email from spam bots?

What are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective method to hide email from spam bots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350750/hiding-email-from-spambots-without-using-javascript) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221195/combat-spambots-by-hiding-email-address-display-none) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769894/how-to-stop-spammers-from-getting-the-email-address-from-a-mailto-link) and lots of others.

Answer (score 13):

### Obscure JavaScript

#### Method

I see this one a lot.

```
My email is <strong id="secret1"></strong>
```

```
var parts = ["secret", "my", 64, "il.com", "gma"];
document.getElementById("secret1").textContent = parts[1] + parts[0] + String.fromCharCode(parts[2]) + parts[4] + parts[3];
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQvvq/)

#### Pros

It's better than plain text, and the **@** character doesn't appear anywhere on your page.

#### Cons

There are now headless browsers that will run JavaScript and look at the dynamic page, instead of the html source.

---

### ::before and ::after

#### Method

Using pseudo selectors in CSS, we can have content appear after an element.  It's never added to the DOM, so it's purely visual.

```
My email is <strong id="secret2">mysecret</strong>
```

```
#secret2::after {
    content: '@gmail.com';
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmLuH/1/)

#### Pros

If you remember to use `::after` instead of `:after`, you can prevent IE<9 users from emailing you.

#### Cons

The user can't select the pseudo element's content.  In the above example, they will have to type "@gmail.com" when emailing you.

---

### Contact Form

#### Method

Provide a contact form, and use a server side script to send the email to you.

```
<h1>Contact Us</h1>

<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <label for="body">Message</label>
    <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/329Xe/)

#### Pros

- you never show your email address, unless you decide to respond
- you can rate limit the form, and provide a captcha
- you can log IP addresses, and block any that send you spam
- you can provide useful options to the user (like multiple choice "what is this about")
- captchas can be used
- you can tie messages to user accounts, and provide updates on the site, along with an archive of previous conversations
- can log browser information (e.g. user-agent) for quicker technical support

#### Cons

- it feels impersonal
- requires a server side language
- takes more time to implement

Comment: "If you remember to use ::after instead of :after, you can prevent IE<9 users from emailing you." LoL good one!